# Adding stuff from github to composer

Tags: git, composer-php

I recently started using composer. I'm really curious how can I add my own repo to composer.json?

I've tried adding

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "url": "https://github.com/cmzyg/quotabox.git",
        "type": "git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "cmzyg/quotabox": "master"
}
}
```

Trying to add this as a test, however when running 'php composer.phar update' I'm getting this error - 'failed to clone, git not found'. Obviously i'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your git project `cmzyg/quotabox` dosn't have a `composer.json`. If this is your own project, you can add a `composer.json`. See here for [how to create a own package](http://grossi.io/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/).

Or if not, you can try this.

```
"repositories": [
    {            
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "cmzyg/quotabox",
            "version": "master",
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://github.com/cmzyg/quotabox/archive/master.zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/cmzyg/quotabox.git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "files": ["autoloader.php"]
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "cmzyg/quotabox": "master-dev"
},
```